Whether $Y$ is in a Lie group $G$ or is in a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ in the formula $Ad_{e^X}Y=e^{ad(X)}Y$?
Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra of $G$. I meet the formula $Ad_{e^X}=e^{ad(X)}$ for $X\in\mathfrak{g}$.
There seems to be a type mismatch in this formula.
I will talk about the parts I understood.
If $G$ is a linear Lie group and we see $G,\mathfrak{g}$ in the set $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ of all matrices, for $Y\in G\cap\mathfrak{g}$, we get $Ad_{e^X}(Y)=e^{ad(X)}Y$.
Here, $Ad_{e^X}:G\to G$, $g\mapsto e^Xge^{-X}$,
$ad(X):\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}$, $Z\mapsto [X,Z]$,
and $e^{ad(X)}:\mathfrak{g}\to G,\ Z\mapsto\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i!}\underbrace{ad(X)\circ\cdots\circ ad(X)}_{i}(Z)$.
However, this condition $Y\in G\cap\mathfrak{g}$ looks strange.
Is $Y$  in $G$ or in $\mathfrak{g}$ ?
Please explain me.

Normally, $Ad$ is reserved for the adjoint representation of the Lie group on the Lie algebra. Where did you find this bizarre notation $G\cap \mathfrak g$?

Thank you for comments. In $Ad_{e^X}(Y)=e^{ad(X)}Y$, $Y$ of the left side seems in $G$ and $Y$ of the right side seems in $\mathfrak{g}$. Therefore, $Y$ is in $G\cap \mathfrak{g}$. Is it true?

No, it is not true. We have $Y\in \mathfrak{g}$, see here, for example.

When something "seems" to be true to you, you should ask yourself "why do I think so." If you cannot answer, then your eyes are probably deceiving you.

Thank you. I mistake the definition of Ad.

Your confusion comes from the fact that you mistook the adjoint representation of $G$, i.e. $\mathrm{Ad} : G \to \mathrm{Inn}(\mathfrak{g}), g \mapsto \mathrm{Ad}_g$, for the Lie group homomorphism $\Psi : G \to \mathrm{Inn}(G), g \mapsto \Psi_g(h) := ghg^{-1}$. Actually, the said adjoint representation is defined as the derivative of the latter (at the identity), i.e. $\mathrm{Ad}_g = (\mathrm{d}\Psi_g)_e$. Since $\Psi_g$ acts on the Lie group $G$, it means that $\mathrm{Ad}_g$ acts on the associated Lie algebra, while being both "indexed" by an element of $G$, according to the appropriate commutative diagram. Now, using the famous exponential map in order to parametrize a curve in $G$ whose tangent vector at the identity is $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, one has in the end :
$$
\mathrm{Ad}_g(X) = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0} \Psi_g(e^{tX}) = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0} ge^{tX}g^{-1} = gXg^{-1}
$$
In consequence, $\Psi_g$ and $\mathrm{Ad}_g$ possess the same functional structure, but the first map corresponds to the action of the Lie group by conjugation on itself, while the second map represents the action of the Lie group by conjugation on the Lie algebra. In conclusion, $Y \in \mathfrak{g}$ in your question.

Thank you very much. I have learnt it.
